# ColdFusion list a particular type of files within folders?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a list of folders from a directory. All of the folders in this directory contain pdf files. There are about 20 folders. Is it possible to get the names of the pdf files, in all folders, without having to go through each directory (folder)?

```
<cfdirectory action="list" 
    directory="C:\wwwroot\WebServer\testing\uploads\all_folders" 
    recurse="false" 
    name="myList">
<cfdump var=#myList#>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `filter="*.pdf"` attribute and `type="file"`.

```
<cfdirectory
    directory="C:\wwwroot\WebServer\testing\uploads\all_folders" 
    action="list" 
    recurse="yes" 
    type="file"
    filter="*.pdf"
    name="myList"
>
<cfdump var=#myList#>
```